# Get a value set via Javascript in a HTTP Post function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding a MVC5 internet application and would like to know how to set a value in `Javascript` in a `View` that can be retrieved in the `View's` `HTTP Post` method.

I have tried this `View` code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="testHiddenField" value="test" />
```

With this `Javascript` code:

```
$("#testHiddenField").val("test value set");
```

However, in the `HTTP Post` method, I am not sure how to retrieve this value.

If the above code is not correct, what is the best way to retrieve a value that is set via `Javascript` in a `MVC View` in the `HTTP Post` function for the `View`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your hidden input needs a `name` attribute in order to post back a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to recover the value at the click of the button submit, or if that 'testHiddenField' is defined in your model , you need to put the name attribute of input , example :

assuming your property in the model is called the 'testHiddenField'

```
public String testHiddenField;
```

when recovered in the post, not forget to put the name in the attribute

```
<input type="hidden" id="testHiddenField" value="test" name="testHiddenField"/>
```

to be recognized in your model, If not set the model . There will be recognized

another solution is Razor:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(input => input.testHiddenField, new {@value="test"})
```

or click of your button submit of form:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn" value="POST">
<script>
   $('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#testHiddenField').val();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way is to do so:

1- in your html code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="testHiddenField" id="testHiddenField" value="test" name="testHiddenField"/>
```

notice I added name attribute to your code.
do what you did in javascript the same way

2- in mvc action do some thing like this by adding testHiddenField as parameter to your action this will make mvc do what we called model binder

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction (string testHiddenField){
// break point here you will find your value is bind to what you set in javascript to view
}
```

if there is any problem contact me
Regards.